# How to make one form control or input-group in a bootstrap inline form expand?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form that right now looks like this:

[image]

and I want it to look like this, that is, the second form control (or in this case input-group) to expand as much as possible while letting the select find its natural size for the text it has inside it:

[image]

But of course, in a fluid manner that will work in all screens (that are wide enough). The code for this form is this:

```
<form class="form-inline role="form">
  <select class="form-control" id="q_radius" name="q[radius]">
    <option value="5">Jobs within 5 miles of</option><!-- more options -->
  </select>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="q_address" name="q[address]" type="text" value="London Bridge, United Kingdom">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is using Bootstrap 3.1.

Is this possible? I think it's not, but I wanted to check with other people before considering it impossible.

Comment: Why the downvotes? What's wrong with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach.. using `display:inline`

```
  <form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group pull-left"> 
    <select class="form-control" id="q_radius" name="q">
      <option value="5">Jobs within 5 miles of</option>
    </select>&nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="q_address" name="a" type="text" value="London Bridge, United Kingdom">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

http://www.bootply.com/gjjuyGKAwf

This approach doesn't have the gap created by wrapping the form controls in Bootstrap's grid `col-*`

Comment: I like this solution but I'm having trouble implementing it. For some reason using the bootstrap-sass gem in Rails fails while using bootstrap from the CDN works and I can't see any differences at all: http://i.imgur.com/CEulk0f.png

Comment: I submitted this as an issue here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/626

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the bootstrap [grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) system to 
accomplish what you want.

I added a bootstrap row and then 2 medium columns inside your form.

**HTML**

```
 <form class="form-inline">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-2">
             <select class="form-control" id="q_radius" name="q[radius]">
                <option value="5">Jobs within 5 miles of</option><!-- more options -->
             </select>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-9">
             <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="q_address" name="q[address]" type="text" value="London Bridge, United Kingdom">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
               </span>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </form>
```

**[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/jKjkry2iI2)**

Comment: I played a bit with a solution like this, but it has the problem of variable size for the select, which looks ugly in all but the perfect size.

Comment: I see, you might try setting a `max-width` on your select?

Answer (score 0):

```
.col-left {
   width: 200px;
   float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }

  .col-right {
     width: calc(100% - 15em);
      float: left;
  }

#q_address {
  width: 90%;
}
```

**HTML:**
Add class `col-left` and `col-right` to the select box and search box.

```
<form class="form-inline role="form">
  <select class="form-control col-left" id="q_radius" name="q[radius]">
    <option value="5">Jobs within 5 miles of</option>
    <option value="10" selected="selected">Jobs within 10 miles of</option>
    <option value="20">Jobs within 20 miles of</option>
    <option value="50">Jobs within 50 miles of</option>
    <option value="100">Jobs within 100 miles of</option>
    <option value="99999">All jobs</option>
  </select>
  <div class="input-group col-right">
    <input class="form-control" id="q_address" name="q[address]" type="text" value="London Bridge, United Kingdom">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Bjwdq)**

Comment: Thank @mohamedrias. The reason why I don't want to use a solution like this one is because it makes the select on the left side grow and shrink and it looks bad when it's too big or too small for its content.

Comment: In that case, define width of select box, use calc() to subtract the width of select. So that the search box takes the remaining width completely

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like this

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HbkGA

Combination of float and margin work good in such type of situation.

HTML

```
<form class="form-inline role="form">
  <div class="select-outer">
    <select class="form-control" id="q_radius" name="q[radius]">
      <option value="5">Jobs within 5 miles of</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </span>
    <div class="input-wrap">
      <input class="form-control" id="q_address" name="q[address]" type="text" value="London Bridge, United Kingdom">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.form-inline .select-outer {
  float:left;
  width: 200px
}
.input-group {
  margin-left: 200px
}

.input-group-btn {
  float:right;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px
}

.input-wrap {
  margin-right: 30px
}

.input-wrap input {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
.fa-search {
  display: inline-block;
}
```